# Resize DrawingImage when grid size changes

Tags: c#, xaml

I have this definition, this DrawingImage has this RectangleGeometry property: Rect="0,0,108,208"

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="ImageDetractor" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Image Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="Detractor" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Image.Source>
                    <DrawingImage PresentationOptions:Freeze="True" x:Name="DrawDetractor">
                        <DrawingImage.Drawing>

                            <DrawingGroup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
                                <DrawingGroup x:Name="DrawingLayer">
                                    <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,108,208" />
                                    </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFE">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M0,0L108,0 108,208 0,208 0,0z" />
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF29C44">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M40.72,20.51C42.58,14.38 48.61,9.88 55,9.73 62.36,9.21 69.56,14.68 70.99,21.91 72.26,28.09 70.08,34.48 66.67,39.61 65.47,41.1 65.82,43.06 65.83,44.82 70.87,44.74 75.92,44.62 80.96,44.8 84.91,44.92 88.95,47.28 90.31,51.11 92.71,58.3 94.47,65.7 96.8,72.92 98.19,77.58 99.53,83.12 96.52,87.45 93.1,92.04 86.96,93.03 81.59,92.77 81.55,126.19 81.57,159.61 81.58,193.03 82,198.23 77.16,203.07 71.97,202.76 67.76,202.58 62.84,203.71 59.37,200.63 55.29,197.78 55.91,192.3 55.66,187.95 55.59,168.46 55.85,148.95 55.52,129.46 55.08,148.3 55.5,167.16 55.32,186.01 55.08,189.8 56.44,193.91 54.54,197.43 52.89,201 48.91,203.16 45.02,202.77 41.33,202.54 37.05,203.61 33.92,201.12 31.34,199.29 29.5,196.32 29.67,193.08 29.69,159.65 29.59,126.22 29.72,92.79 25.34,93.78 20.3,94.35 16.42,91.57 12.61,89.04 11.38,83.98 12.69,79.74 15.29,70.59 17.88,61.43 20.55,52.3 21.62,48.07 25.66,45.11 29.94,44.84 35.14,44.53 40.36,44.9 45.56,44.67 45.53,43.7 45.47,41.75 45.44,40.77 41.03,35.11 39.01,27.55 40.72,20.51z" />
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFE">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M43.66,21.44C45.29,15.4 51.94,11.56 58.01,12.84 63.43,13.69 67.68,18.56 68.17,23.97 68.63,29.75 66.25,35.41 62.74,39.9 62.72,42.39 62.71,44.89 62.69,47.38 69.11,48.27 75.61,47.32 82.05,47.87 84.83,48.22 87.14,50.44 87.77,53.15 89.9,60.28 91.92,67.45 94.04,74.59 95.09,78.4 96.15,83.03 93.48,86.44 90.57,89.61 85.97,89.94 81.94,89.85 68.16,89.69 54.36,90.08 40.58,89.65 42.57,87.48 45.76,87.37 48.35,86.3 56.84,83.23 65.69,81.03 73.84,77.09 75.95,76.78 78.99,77.4 78.43,74.18 76.96,74.13 75.5,74.09 74.04,74.04 73.36,70.9 71.98,67.51 68.71,66.34 63.23,64.53 57.32,65.85 51.82,66.94 45.66,68.57 39.38,69.77 33.28,71.6 33.59,72.15 34.22,73.23 34.54,73.78 45.06,72.54 55.14,67.43 65.91,68.53 69.05,68.84 70.88,71.91 70.87,74.85 69.97,76.04 68.4,76.39 67.09,76.96 54.08,81.36 41.04,85.68 28.03,90.05 24.34,91.21 19.64,91.19 16.94,88.03 14.69,85.56 15.19,81.93 16.06,79 18.64,70.38 21,61.71 23.54,53.08 24.23,50.14 26.93,47.98 29.92,47.82 36.14,47.4 42.4,48.21 48.6,47.39 48.58,44.91 48.58,42.43 48.57,39.95 44.59,34.78 42,27.98 43.66,21.44z" />
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFE">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M32.71,91.68C33.82,91.22 34.9,90.68 36.07,90.4 38.33,91.24 40.39,92.87 42.93,92.69 54.77,92.73 66.62,92.7 78.47,92.69 78.55,126.12 78.5,159.55 78.5,192.98 78.78,196.6 75.62,199.86 72.06,199.99 68.57,200.17 64.54,200.7 61.52,198.56 57.94,195.84 59.07,190.85 58.99,186.97 59.02,168.3 58.79,149.63 59.03,130.96 59.4,128.69 57.46,126.14 55.05,126.73 52.95,126.88 52.21,129.24 52.39,131.02 52.4,151.7 52.44,172.38 52.38,193.06 52.5,196.23 50.11,199.28 46.98,199.83 43.99,200.32 40.9,200.31 37.92,199.76 34.91,199.13 32.74,196.11 32.85,193.07 32.69,159.28 32.96,125.47 32.71,91.68z" />
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingGroup>

                        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    </DrawingImage>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

When I maximize/resize my window, my image stays in the mentioned size, I need my image gets resized
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a good example of this. In my example I am drawing to a Grid using a ViewModel and then it updates whenever the window is resized.

Try this in your xaml

```
    <Window x:Class="GraphApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:GraphApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="400*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Width="100" Height="30" Content="update" Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommand}"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="GraphGrid" Grid.Row="1"> 
            <ViewModel:BasicGraph x:Name="BasicGraphE" Width="{Binding ElementName=GraphGrid, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                  Height="{Binding ElementName=GraphGrid, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                  ></ViewModel:BasicGraph>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now for the view model
Add this code

```
    namespace GraphApp
{    
    public class BasicGraph:FrameworkElement
    {
    Canvas Graph;
    VisualCollection vc;
    DrawingContext dc;
    double x_center;
    double y_center;

    public BasicGraph()
    {
        vc  = new VisualCollection(this);
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Draw_Loaded);
        this.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(Draw_Updated);
    }

    public void UpdateLayout()
    {
        this.UpdateLayout();
    }
    void DrawAxes()
    {
        Point leftMid = new Point(0,this.ActualHeight/2);
        Point rightMid = new Point(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight / 2);
        Point topMid = new Point(this.ActualWidth / 2, 0);
        Point bottomMid = new Point(this.ActualWidth / 2, this.ActualHeight); 
        DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
        {
            dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1.0), leftMid, rightMid);
            dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1.0), topMid, bottomMid);
        }
        vc.Add(dv);
    }

    void DrawLinePoint(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        DrawAxes();
    }

    void Draw_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        DrawAxes();
        // DrawLinePoint(new Point(1.5, 1.5), new Point(50.0, 50.0));
    }

    void Draw_Updated(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        vc.Clear();
        DrawAxes();
    }


    void GenerateAxes(Canvas GraphWindow)
    {
        double width = GraphWindow.Width;
        double height = GraphWindow.Height;            
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return vc[index];
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return vc.Count;
        }
    }


}
}
```

Framework element basically tells the compiler this is something that will be drawn on the screen.

Draw_Updated <- Gets called whenever you resize a window. This has to clear the drawing and redraw.

These are my using statements in case you are wondering

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```